# Constness of captured reference

Tags: c++11, constants

An object can be captured by mutable reference, and changed inside a member function which takes the same object as `const`.

```
void g(const int& x, std::function<void()> f)
{
  std::cout << x << '\n';
  f();
  std::cout << x << '\n';
}

int main()
{
  int y = 0;
  auto f = [&y] { ++y; };
  g(y, f);
}
```

An object is mutated in a scope where it is `const`. I understand that the compiler can't enforce constness here without proving that `x` and `y` are aliases. I suppose all I'm looking for is confirmation that this is undefined behavior. Is it equivalent in some sense to a `const_cast` - using a value as non-`const` in a context where it should be?

Comment: Just because `x` refers to a `const int` doesn't mean the thing it refers to can't be modified, it's just an unnecessary qualifier. Doing `++const_cast<int &>(x);` would be just as well-defined since `y` is not const.

Comment: I wonder if this fails strict aliasing rules, since there are two references to the same variable? That would certainly make it undefined behavior.

Comment: @MarkRansom, Hmm, that's an interesting thought.

Comment: @MarkRansom, I don't think so; modifying an `int` using an `int` reference certainly does not run awry of strict aliasing rules. It doesn't matter how many references exist.

Comment: @chris Do you mean to say that using const_cast in that case (and this one) would not be UB?

Comment: @roysc, In general, using `const_cast` to modify the referred to object of a `const T &` is not UB as long as the referred to object itself is not `const`.

Comment: @chris But from within the function's scope, the object is declared `const`. If this is well-defined behavior, doesn't that imply `const` params actually offer no semantic guarantees?

Comment: @roysc, well, it offers semantic guarantees to the *caller*.

Comment: @roysc, From what I know, the `const` keyword is pretty much more useful for self-documentation than semantics. `const` parameters are a useful tool, but like everything else in C++, they can be used seemingly pointlessly by saying you're not going to modify something and then modifying it. It's up to you to make reasonable guarantees and not actively try to get around them.

Comment: @MarkRansom Strict aliasing forbids forming a reference of the wrong type, a.k.a. type punning. It would be very difficult to program a system where no two pointers/references could alias, ever.

Comment: Note that if you promise to the compiler they are no alias (with `restrict`), local var may be not modified as in https://ideone.com/Th6xZA. But as you lie to your compiler, you may have problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reference or pointer to const doesn't mean the referenced object cannot be modified at all - it just means that the object cannot be modified **via this reference/pointer**. It may very well be modified via another reference/pointer to the same object. This is called [aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_%28computing%29).

Here's an example that doesn't use lambdas or any other fancy features:

```
int x = 0;

void f() { x = 42; }

void g(const int& y) {
  cout << y;
  f();
  cout << y;
}

int main() {
  g(x);
}
```

There's nothing undefined going on, because the object itself is not `const`, and constness on aliases is primarily for the *user's* benefit. For thoroughness, the relevant section is `[dcl.type.cv]p3`:

> A pointer or reference to a cv-qualiﬁed type need not actually point
>   or refer to a cv-qualiﬁed object, but it is treated as if it does; a
>   const-qualiﬁed access path cannot be used to modify an object even if
>   the object referenced is a non-const object **and can be modiﬁed
>   through some other access path**. [ Note: Cv-qualiﬁers
>   are supported by the type system so that they cannot be subverted without casting (5.2.11). —end note ]

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of aliasing, just not how it's treated by the language. I'd like to make a quick edit to add a reference to the standard.